# Railway app not able to install when deploying NestJS application

Tags: node.js, typescript, deployment, nestjs, railway

I am trying to deploy a NestJS application on Railway.

I am using NPM as my package manager.

I have explicitly defined a run command and a build command in the project settings.

[image]

Whenever I try to deploy the project, I get the following error.

```
#13 3.042 npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
#13 3.134 npm ERR! Missing script: "install"
 
#13 3.134 npm ERR!
#13 3.134 npm ERR! Did you mean this?
#13 3.134 npm ERR!     npm uninstall # Remove a package
#13 3.135 npm ERR!
#13 3.135 npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
#13 3.135 npm ERR!   npm run
#13 3.137
#13 3.137 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#13 3.137 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-01-14T18_01_46_797Z-debug-0.log
```

Has anybody experienced this before, where it can't recognize the install command?

I have tried with and without the custom build command, but every time it fails when running the `npm run install` step in the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

I think the command that should run to install is `npm install` instead of `npm run install`. Have you tried checking the package.json file and tried adding `"install": "npm install"` inside scripts